# Attempted import error: 'AnchorProvider' is not exported from '@project-serum/anchor'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, runtime-error, jsx, anchor-solana

I got this problem when trying to run my react app.

**The problem:**
*Attempted import error: 'AnchorProvider' is not exported from '@project-serum/anchor'.*

**The import inside my code:**

```
import idl from './idl.json';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import twitterLogo from "./assets/twitter-logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { Connection, PublicKey, clusterApiUrl } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { Program, AnchorProvider, web3 } from '@project-serum/anchor';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
```

**The getProvider function:**

```
 const getProvider = () => {
  const connection = new Connection(network, opts.preflightCommitment);
  const provider = new AnchorProvider(
    connection,
    window.solana,
    opts.preflightCommitment
  );
  return provider;
};

const createGifAccount = async () => {
  try {
    const provider = getProvider();
    const program = new Program(idl, programID, provider);
    console.log("ping");
    await program.rpc.startStuffOff({
      accounts: {
        baseAccount: baseAccount.publicKey,
        user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
        systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
      },
      signers: [baseAccount],
    });
    console.log(
      "BaseAccount criado com sucesso com o endereço :",
      baseAccount.publicKey.toString()
    );
    await getGifList();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Erro criando uma nova BaseAccount:", error);
  }
};
```

**My project-serum version** "@project-serum/anchor": "^0.18.2".

I am quite lost with this problem, so I don't really know what to do that could fix it. Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

update @project-serum/anchor to latest version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with supporting information, explaining how this solves the issue as well supporting links to documentation/tutorials.